# In Trello, how do I insert an HTML entity in a card comment?

Tags: trello, markdown

According to the [markdown syntax guide](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autoescape) you can just insert HTML entities directly (e.g `&copy;` for ©). However, HTML entities don't seem to work in Trello comments (which use markdown)—the entity code appears as-is.

Comment: Just tried it myself, you can add certain markdown in the card description, like links, however the copyright symbol does not work.

Comment: Yeah, actually I was specially interested in inserting the tick symbol &amp;&#10004; (&#10004;) to mark some of the sub-items of a task as complete.

Comment: Ironically Html entities do not work in the comments of this site either ! :)  (not a coincidence I guess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the HTML entity, you can insert the character itself in Trello list titles, card titles and descriptions (and even comments, which do not support Markdown).  Usually, when I need a special character, I do a web search to find the a website that uses the sought character, copy it (<kbd>CTRL/CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste it where I need it (<kbd>CTRL/CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). That's what I just did to insert the tick character here: ✔! (@Spam n Eggs, clearly the same can be done for Stack Exchange comments).

There are plenty of websites that provide charts of special characters, like [this one](http://www.edlazorvfx.com/ysu/html/ascii.html).

If you'd like a handier way of inserting the tick symbol, you could:

- Try an autocorrect/text-replacement program.  These will run in the background and work across programs.  Many find them highly useful for many typing tasks.  Create a rule so that whenever you type a certain string (i.e "[tick]") it's replaced with "✔".
- If you're on a Mac, you can access the Character Viewer directly from the menu bar to insert characters.  On Windows, it's the Character Map.

Comment: ✔ - oh yeah that worked! By the way I like the idea of the autocorrect tool, do you know of any options for linux?

Comment: I have never had a need for a text expansion tool when working on Linux, but [here is a recommendation](http://lifehacker.com/5845445/the-best-text-expansion-app-for-linux) from Lifehacker.